# Remove or Hide all logs in Kibana for a particular container

Tags: containers, logstash, kibana

I am setting up the EFK stack for my containerized environment. I have given /var/lib/docker/containers/*.log to get logs from all the containers and it is working fine.

Now I saw some strange logs generated by one of my containers and I decided to not show them on Kibana dashboard.

```
@timestamp         August 30th 2019, 13:44:59.136
_id                 XXX
_index              filebeat-6.0.1-2019.08.30
_score              - 
_type               doc
beat.namexyz        xyz.com
beat.version        6.0.1
container.name      mycontainer
property            mycontainerproperty
log:
```

How can I hide the entries for this container?

I thought not to take the logs from this container in the first place but the container ID is not going to be the same every time. so excluding it in the input section seems impossible.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea here. Is there any grok pattern that I can use to hide entries for this container?

Comment: So what's the unique features of these weird logs? You'll need something to filter on. Is the `log` attribute empty?

Comment: Well generally spoken you need a logstash filter to decide if you want to drop the events or not. You need some criteria for that decision. In my opinion the contents of the **log** field should be that determinator. So please provide us some values of the log field for these particularly events.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill
yes these logs are unique. The log content start with **"DEBU: 2019/09/03 09:27:43.373081 EVENT AddPod"** and so on.
Apart from these log entries none of my containers logs start with the "DEBU" keyword. 
Please let me know if more details required.

Comment: So is it save to assume that you want to ignore/drop all log events that start with **DEBU** ?

Comment: yes.. @apt-get_install_skill. All logs that start with DEBU. Or if we can hide them based on the other fields associated with this log such as property=mycontainerproperty, which is also unique for such logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as stated from the OP in the comments the events that should be dropped start with the value **DEBU:** in the log field.

Here's a logstash filter (untested) that checks if the value of the log field matches this criteria. If so, the event will dropped which means it will **not** be indexed into Elasticsearch.

```
filter{
  grok{
    match => { "log" => "^DEBU:.*" }
    tag_on_failure => [ "event_should_not_be_dropped" ]
  }

  if "event_should_not_be_dropped" not in [tags]{
    drop { }
  }
}
```

With the grok plugin we check if the value of the log field start with **DEBU:**. If not, the event will be tagged. If the event is not tagged the whole event will be dropped.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: I used the above filter but getting, "No processor type exists with name [drop]". I am using elasticsearch 6.2.4 and the same version of the filebeat.

Comment: Please share your filter config file and your logstash configuration then.

Comment: well I was using the above filter in my elasticsearch pipeline (that we place in kibana Dev tools). Today I tried the same thing in my filebeat.yml file and it worked. 
my code snippet looks similar to this- 
`
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
            namespace: ${POD_NAMESPACE}
            include_annotations:
              - "build"
              - "branch-name"
        - drop_event.when:
              - equals:
                  kubernetes.container.name: "container_to_hide"
`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a solution to the above situation- 
I edit my filebeat.yml and put the drop filter/processor.

My filebeat.yml looks like-

```
data:
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - type: log
      paths:
        - /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
      json.message_key: log
      json.keys_under_root: true

      multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
      multiline.negate: true
      multiline.match: 'after'
      scan_frequency: 20s
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
            namespace: ${POD_NAMESPACE}
            include_annotations:
              - "build"
              - "branch-name"
        - drop_event.when:
            or:
              - equals:
                  property: "mycontaininerproperty"
              - equals:
                  label: "mycontainerlabel"
```

so now if any of the log entries contains property="mycontainerproperty" or label="mycontainerlebel". It will drop those entries.